# Azure DevOps: Application Error If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops

I am trying to publish Hello-world to azure app service.
I am using below code from my git repo as below

https://github.com/biswajeetbehera/java-hello-world-with-maven/tree/master/src/main/java/hello

I am using Azure-DevOps CI-CD pipeline to build my code from above URL & using maven as my build tool inside it.

after successfully building my package I am trying to deploy it on Azure app service {its a Linux server. I have installed java inside it.)

But I am getting below error:

> :( Application Error
>   If you are the application administrator, you can access the diagnostic resources.

Comment: What have you found on Azure system logs?

Answer (score 1):

Following things which you can take a look at,

1) Did you try to build at your local machine , did it compiled successfully.
Using the same command which has been triggered with azure devops.

2) Did you have all the dependency installed in the build agent?

3) Here you can find the respected link for maven task for an application

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/maven?view=azure-devops
```

Please check that and see if it helps.

Comment: 2019-04-29T22:33:51.720149569Z STARTUP_COMMAND=StreamPlayerEventLauncher.java
2019-04-29T22:33:51.720173770Z No STARTUP_FILE available.
2019-04-29T22:33:51.720179370Z Running STARTUP_COMMAND: StreamPlayerEventLauncher.java
2019-04-29T22:33:51.720183770Z Finished running startup command 'StreamPlayerEventLauncher.java'. Exiting with exit code 127.
2019-04-29T22:33:51.720141369Z /bin/init_container.sh: line 122: StreamPlayerEventLauncher.java: command not found

Comment: my build & deployment is successful

Comment: @BiswajeetBehera what was your solution?